# Generic built-in EventArgs to hold only one property?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, events, fcl

I have a number of EventArgs classes with only one field and an appropriate property to read it:

```
public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly Foo f;
    public SomeEventArgs(Foo f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }
    public Foo Foo
    {
        get { return this.f; }
    }    
}
```

Is there any built-in, generic class to implement such behavior or I have to roll my own?

```
public class GenericEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    private readonly T value;
    public GenericEventArgs(T v)
    {
        this.value = v;
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }    
}
```

P.S.
I wrote a [suggestion on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/569001/generic-eventargs-eventargs-t)

Comment: There are implementations of `DataEventArgs<TData>` in some Microsoft assemblies/namespaces. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312134/does-net-have-a-built-in-eventargst/15896769#15896769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is.
Looks like you are not the only one to ask himself this question.
Take a look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/customgenericeventargs05132007100456AM/customgenericeventargs.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If there *is* one, it certainly isn't well publicised! (i.e. it's not something you're *meant* to use for general purpose stuff, like `Func<T>`.) I've thought about the same thing myself before now. It's not a rare requirement, IMO.

One downside of this is that it doesn't have a meaningful name for the property, of course - it's like an `EventArgs` equivalent of `Tuple`. But if you have several different use cases for this and it *will* actually be obvious what the meaning is, go for it :)

Comment: @Itay's link follows to interesting name: just `EventArgs<T>`. It's very interesting why FCL doesn't contain yet such very useful class!

Answer (score 2):

On this page at bottom you can see all classes are inherited from EventArgs class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx

The most appropriate is ReturnEventArgs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615572.aspx but this class is located in PresentationFramework.dll, that is only referenced by WPF projects.

So I recommend to create your own one.