# Why can't I just use EventHandler<int> instead of deriving from EventArgs

Tags: c#, .net

The documentation for [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) says:

> The second parameter is a type derived from EventArgs and supplies
>   any fields or properties needed to hold the event data.

and it seems to be generally recommended throughout the .Net documentation.

However it turns out that I can do the following which works just fine:

```
public event EventHandler<int> Panned;
```

and invoke the event handler as:

```
int value = 10;
if (Panned != null)
{
    Panned(this, value);
}
```

and on the observer side:

```
subject.Panned += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
};
```

To me this seems better than littering the code with little classes that inherit from `EventArgs` or having a generic `EventArgs` as proposed by [Does .NET have a built-in EventArgs<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312134/does-net-have-a-built-in-eventargst)

So why is it required that I inherit the `EventHandler` generic argument from `EventArgs`?

Comment: If you use .NET 4.0 or older `public event EventHandler<int> Panned;` would fail. [In 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.100).aspx) it had a `where TEventArgs : EventArgs` constraint on it. That constraint was dropped [in 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh interesting. That's good to know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If all you need to do is pass an `int` to the handler then what you are doing is fine.

It *used* to be the case (*before*  .NET 4.5) that the `EventHandler` type argument `TEventArgs` was constrained to inherit from `EventArgs` but not anymore:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

The fact that MS dropped the constraint should tell you that they were being too strict and what you are doing is fine.

In the case that you need to pass a complex type to the handler then you *might aswell* inherit `EventArgs` for reasons of polymorphism. Also, the `EventArgs.Empty` member is useful.

Comment: Also, if your event doesn't wire up with a derivative of the default `EventHandler` delegate, powershell (at least up to 4) will fail miserably and crash if you try to set a handler using `Register-ObjectEvent`

Answer (score 7):

This is just a convention. In fact, you don't even have to use the `EventHandler<>` generic delegate. You could have:

```
public event Action SomeEvent;

public void OnAction()
{
    var a = this.SomeEvent;
    if (a != null)
    {
        a();
    }
}
```

Of course, the convention is there for a reason. As far as I know, *every* standard .NET event follows the pattern of using a void-returning delegate that takes an `object` parameter and a second parameter of `EventArgs` or a derived type. This makes it easy to use these events without having to refer to the documentation each time.

## Silly, Silly, Silly!

Will this work?...

```
class Program
{
    public static event Func<int> SomeEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeEvent += () => 7;
        SomeEvent += () => 8;
        var a = SomeEvent();
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

I tried it: it does! Of course, it's very odd to have an event where the delegate has a return value, because it's not obvious which handler's value will be returned to the caller if there are multiple attached handlers. In the above example, it turns out that `8` is written to the console.

Interesting but, I suspect, useless ;-)

## Would You Ever Use This?

I don't *think* it would ever be sensible to have a non-void returning delegate type, as in my example. However, you might *consider* using a delegate whose parameters are value types (structs, not classes) for performance reasons. It might be possible to use events without incurring the garbage collection penalty of allocating `EventArgs` objects on the heap.